# How to Access Query Fetched from Oracle in PHP Smarty Template?

Tags: php, smarty

SO basiacally i have a query which i run and apply "while($item = oci_fetch_assoc($stid))" and i am confused how to take the rows seprately in one object and pass it to smarty template and show it in the table in smarty.

Answer (score 0):

Build the entire rowset array, then pass that to your templating engine

```
$rowset = array();
while($item = oci_fetch_assoc($stid)) {
    $rowset[] = $item;
}

$smarty->assign($rowset); // Haven't used smarty in years, just guessing here
```

Comment: No just Figureed that out: So basically $i=1;
while($row =oci_fetch_assoc($stid)){

        foreach($row as $key=>$value){
         $data_row[$i][$key]=$value;
        }
        $i++;
        }

Answer (score 0):

So basically we have to do something like :
$i=1;
while($row =oci_fetch_assoc($stid)){

```
    foreach($row as $key=>$value){
     $data_row[$i][$key]=$value;
    }
    $i++;
    }
```

SO this way $data_row[][] will be every entry and assign it to smarty. 
In Smarty we will access it by :
{foreach from=$row key=myid item=foo}

{$foo.key1}
{$foo.key2}
{$foo.key3}
and so on
{/foreach}

or whatever ur key is